# How to replicate pandas DataFrame rows and change periodically one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, repeat

I have df going like

```
pd.DataFrame([["A1"     "B1",      "C1", "P"],
              ["A2"     "B2",      "C2", "P"],
              ["A3"     "B3",      "C3", "P"]], columns=["col_a"  "col_b",   "col_c", "col_d"])


col_a  col_b   col_c col_d
A1     B1      C1    P
A2     B2      C2    P
A3     B3      C3    P
...
```

the result I need is basically repeat and ensure that columns have P Q R extension in col_d for every unique row occurence

```
col_a  col_b   col_c col_d
A1     B1      C1    P
A1     B1      C1    Q
A1     B1      C1    R

A2     B2      C2    P
A2     B2      C2    Q
A2     B2      C2    R

A3     B3      C3    P
A3     B3      C3    Q
A3     B3      C3    R
...
```

All I have so far is:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, 3, axis=0), columns=df.columns)
```

Which result in duplication of those values, but col_d is unchanged

EDIT:

Now I stumbled upon another need, where for every unique col_a and col_b I need to add "S" to col_d

Resulting for instance in this:

```
col_a  col_b   col_c col_d
A1     B1      C1    P
A1     B1      C1    Q
A1     B1      C1    R
A1     B1       T    S

A2     B2      C2    P
A2     B2      C2    Q
A2     B2      C2    R
A2     B2       T    S
```

Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add values to column `col_d` by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
L = ['P','Q','R']
new_df = (pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, 3, axis=0), columns=df.columns)
           .assign(col_d = np.tile(L, len(df))))

print (new_df)
  col_acol_b col_c col_d
0       A1B1    C1     P
1       A1B1    C1     Q
2       A1B1    C1     R
3       A2B2    C2     P
4       A2B2    C2     Q
5       A2B2    C2     R
6       A3B3    C3     P
7       A3B3    C3     Q
8       A3B3    C3     R
```

Another similar idea is repeat indices and duplicated rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
L = ['P','Q','R']
new_df = (df.loc[df.index.repeat(3)]
            .assign(col_d = np.tile(L, len(df)))
            .reset_index(drop=True))

print (new_df)
  col_acol_b col_c col_d
0       A1B1    C1     P
1       A1B1    C1     Q
2       A1B1    C1     R
3       A2B2    C2     P
4       A2B2    C2     Q
5       A2B2    C2     R
6       A3B3    C3     P
7       A3B3    C3     Q
8       A3B3    C3     R
```

EDIT:

```
L = ['P','Q','R','S']
new_df = (pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, len(L), axis=0), columns=df.columns)
           .assign(col_d = np.tile(L, len(df)),
                   col_c = lambda x: x['col_c'].mask(x['col_d'].eq('S'), 'T')))

print (new_df)
   col_acol_b col_c col_d
0        A1B1    C1     P
1        A1B1    C1     Q
2        A1B1    C1     R
3        A1B1     T     S
4        A2B2    C2     P
5        A2B2    C2     Q
6        A2B2    C2     R
7        A2B2     T     S
8        A3B3    C3     P
9        A3B3    C3     Q
10       A3B3    C3     R
11       A3B3     T     S
```

Comment: That is great and it works! 
Now I stumbled upon another need, where for every unique col_a and col_b I need to add "S" to col_d 

Resulting for instance in this:
```
col_a  col_b   col_c col_d
A1     B1      C1    P
A1     B1      C1    Q
A1     B1      C1    R
A1     B1       T      S

A2     B2      C2    P
A2     B2      C2    Q
A2     B2      C2    R
A2     B2       T      S
```

Comment: I added it to question

Comment: @DisplayedName - Can you check edit?

Comment: Sir, you are a genious. Thank you very much ! 
Where did you learned such skills with pandas?

Comment: @DisplayedName - Many hours of coding ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the first dataframe you can [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
l= ['P','Q','R']
new_df = df.assign(col_d=[l]*len(df)).explode('col_d')
```

or [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
new_df = df.drop(columns='col_d').merge(pd.Series(l, name='col_d'), how='cross')
```

output:

```
  col_acol_b col_c col_d
0       A1B1    C1     P
1       A1B1    C1     Q
2       A1B1    C1     R
3       A2B2    C2     P
4       A2B2    C2     Q
5       A2B2    C2     R
6       A3B3    C3     P
7       A3B3    C3     Q
8       A3B3    C3     R
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily generate the combinations with [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor 

df.complete(['col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c'], {'col_d': ['P','Q','R']})

  col_a col_b col_c col_d
0    A1    B1    C1     P
1    A1    B1    C1     Q
2    A1    B1    C1     R
3    A2    B2    C2     P
4    A2    B2    C2     Q
5    A2    B2    C2     R
6    A3    B3    C3     P
7    A3    B3    C3     Q
8    A3    B3    C3     R
```

Basically, you are combining `['col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c']` with `{'col_d': ['P','Q','R']}`; using a dictionary allows you to introduce new values into the data.

For the scenario where you need to introduce `S`, you can break down the steps:

```py
(df
.complete(['col_a', 'col_b'], {'col_d': ['P','Q','R', 'S']})
.assign(col_c = lambda df: np.where(df.col_d.eq('S'), 'T', df.col_c))
.ffill()
)

   col_a col_b col_c col_d
0     A1    B1    C1     P
1     A1    B1    C1     Q
2     A1    B1    C1     R
3     A1    B1     T     S
4     A2    B2    C2     P
5     A2    B2    C2     Q
6     A2    B2    C2     R
7     A2    B2     T     S
8     A3    B3    C3     P
9     A3    B3    C3     Q
10    A3    B3    C3     R
11    A3    B3     T     S
```

Comment: always the nice janitor ;)